# PhalconPHP: How to set a Selected option in SELECT tag

Tags: php, phalcon

I want to set the `<option>` with the value coming from Db.
So far I tried this but not working:

```
$site_select = new Select('site_id', $this->_sites);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

Generating the select using DB columns as Timothy recommended:

```
new Select('site_id', Sites::find(), array('using' => array('site_id', 'site_name')));
```

Setting the selected value of the given select:

```
$site_select->setDefault('YOUR_DB_VALUE');
```

However there is another lovely trick about Phalcon forms. You could pass your DB entity to the form class and your form will be auto populated.

**Form:**

```
class YourFormClass extends Phalcon\Forms\Form
{
    public function initialize($entity = null, $options = null)
    {
```

**Controller:**

```
$entity = YourModel::findFirst();
$form = new YourFormClass ($entity, $options);
```

Note that Form input names must match DB/Model columns.

Comment: If you only want to populate the `select` instead of the whole `form`, you can do this instead: `new Select('site_id', Sites::find(), array('using' => array('site_id', 'site_name')));`. Where `site_id` and `site_name` are the database column names. And ofcourse, you will have to use `setDefault` to select your default value.

Comment: Ah, Timothy you are right. Updated my answer with example for generating the select, I misunderstood Volatile's question, thought he wanted to set selected option of the select.