# How select a select input type in phalcon form?

Tags: phalcon

I have a select type in phalcon form

```
$category = new Select('category', Category::findForSelect(), [
            'useEmpty' => true,
            'emptyText' => 'Select...',
            'emptyValue' => ''
        ]);
```

It works on new form. When i edit the form with old data the category does not get selected on edit.

Comment: Similar question was answered few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38239846/phalconphp-how-to-set-a-selected-option-in-select-tag Does this help you?

Comment: What is the output of `Category::findForSelect()` ?

Comment: its just an id as key and category name as value

Comment: So your problem is that you can't add selected to the chosen option? Have you tried passing entity to the form or using setDefault() on the select?